# App crashes on loading modal window

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsexception

So I'm new to working with Xcode and trying to fix an existing app. The trouble I'm having is with loading in a HTML file into a modal window.

This is the code I think is relevant:

```
-(void) loadScreen
{
    [super loadScreen];


    formView = [[ontracHazardsFormSheetViewController alloc] init];
    [formView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    formView.urlToLoad = [self.urlToLoadstringByAppendingString:@"/redzone"];
    formView.cookieValue = self.cookieValue;
    formView.dataObject = self.dataObject;
    formView.htmlString = self.redzoneHTMLString;
    [formView loadScreen];


}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    NSMutableArray *array = [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems mutableCopy];

    UIBarButtonItem *redZoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Red Zones" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(displayRedZones:)];
    redZoneButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [array addObject:redZoneButton];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = array;

}
-(IBAction)displayRedZones:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"red zones");


    [self presentViewController:formView animated:NO completion:nil];


    //ontracWebViewController

}
```

I have a button that launches displayRedZones and when I use it the following crash report is produced:

```
2016-03-30 14:05:55.539 eCoss[3680:1292033] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController _defaultAnimationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15710d10'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2265c10b 0x21e02e17 0x22661925 0x2265f559 0x2258fc08 0x26b05e03 0x267a7651 0x26b05d69 0x2689a979 0x268c631d 0x268c50b1 0x22e697bd 0x2261fe1f 0x2261fa51 0x2261d89d 0x22570bf9 0x225709e5 0x237bcac9 0x26800ba1 0xd1ac1 0x2221f873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Xcode also show this when the app crashes:

[image]

Like I said I'm completely new to using Xcode and IOS development full stop so if I've not included something crucial please forgive me and let me know.

thanks

Comment: Xcode is crashing, or your app is crashing?

Comment: The app, Xcode is fine

Comment: Please fix the title of your question then.

Comment: damn that's a poor question :/

Comment: Thanks, didn't even realise

Comment: OK next you need a decent stacktrace. If you are running this in Xcode it should halt where it crashes and you should be able to view the stack.  That list of numbers needs to be symbolicated if running outside of Xcode.

Comment: App is crashing on iPhone simulator or iPad?

Comment: @RonakChaniyara It's on an iPad device.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok so I've updated to question with what i think is what you're asking for

Comment: No that's too late; you need to add an *exception breakpoint* so the debugger will break at the time of the exception.

Comment: @trojanfoe OK so I dont know if it's related but if i breakpoint on the presentViewController line I get `[_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController _defaultAnimationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` After this the normal error comes in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

***For iPhone:***

```
[self presentViewController: formView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

***For iPad:***

```
UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:formView];

    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Like,

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self presentViewController:formView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    // Change Rect to position Popover
    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:formView];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMakeCGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Note: Do modification as per reqiurement.